# Escape Unicode Control Commands in AutoCAD Text Field

Tags: autocad

How do you escape the Unicode control commands in a text line? I have a string "%%P123" I want my text line to show but it keeps coming out as "±123" because %%P is treated as the plus/minus symbol

Answer (score 1):

Use `%%%%P123`, but you'll have to edit the Contents property through the Properties Palette, as the standard `TEXT` command will automatically evaluate a double `%%`.

[image]

Comment: Lee, thank you for the response. Unfortunately I'm updating these values (~1000) via Data Link and can't edit each text lines Contents manually.       P.S. Huge fan of the BATTE program